# Half of code is offset

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue of everything after my jumbotron being offset and not staying within the container. I double checked that I had everything closed and with the proper cols but I can't seem to find what's cuasing it to not line up. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks6Y5.jpg

I'm using default CSS

Has anyone run into this yet?

```html
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h1>New Year, New Website</h1>
                    <p style="padding-left:10px; padding-right: 10px;">We’re pleased to announce that on Tuesday, January 9, Meridian Bank will officially launch a new and refreshed website!</p><br>
                    <hr style="height:3px;color:#ba0c2f;background-color:#ba0c2f;border:none;margin-top: 0px;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <img src="https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4683/38610459925_123f07dc11_o.png" class="img-responsive" width="100%" height="auto" alt="website-hero-compressor">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-top:20px;">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="mailto:info@meridianbanker.com" role="button">Questions? »</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                <h1>Time To Get Excited</h1>
                <p>Over the last year we analyzed valuable customer feedback, industry best practices and the latest in user design to develop a site that reflects our commitment to providing cutting-edge financial technology and unparalleled personal service. </p>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <hr style="height:3px;color:#ba0c2f;background-color:#ba0c2f;border: none;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom: 10px;">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px;">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                <div style="position:relative;">
                    <div style="position:relative;padding-bottom:54%;"><iframe src="https://gfycat.com/ifr/RemotePlasticEastsiberianlaika" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width='100%' height='100%' style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container well">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="media">
                        <div class="media-body"> etc etc etc
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer but I see that You close jumbotron after first "container".

Comment: after talking with some support I found it was the landing page client I was using to publish was forcing a page width that for some reason only affected the jumbotron.

For anyone else having this problem, make sure that the host isn't effecting your code in anyway (acton in my case)

Answer (score 0):

after talking with some support I found it was the landing page client I was using to publish was forcing a page width that for some reason only affected the jumbotron.

For anyone else having this problem, make sure that the host isn't effecting your code in anyway (acton in my case)

Comment: hosting affecting CSS ? it's new to me :)